# How do I connect a new light fixture that has two black and two white wires?

Tags: electrical

I just took down a chain chandelier. In the ceiling I have one black, one white, and one bare ground wire. The new light fixture has 4 wires two black and two white. How would I wire the new fixture?

Answer (score 1):

Combine the 2 white from the new fixture to the white from the box, then connect the 2 black from the light to the black in the box, last connect the bare ground in the box to the metal strap that the lamp hangs from, If there is no metal strap or the new fixture is not metal tuck the bare ground up in the box and mount the new fixture.

Comment: This doesn't provide any explanation for why this works or why the lamp isn't defective for having these.

Comment: The op is only asking on how to wire this is what was provided.

Comment: That's your opinion, Ed.  I for one think people want a little more background info. That's why I provided that in my answer, which was designed to complement (support) yours without stepping on your toes.  Guess you didn't like that, eh.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The background info is useful, but Ed's point is valid. Why don't you just edit your answer and add the info the OP asked for?

Comment: @harper I do have opinions, let’s go to court on this and I would win because I am a professional and you are an internet only electrician. You can  wait for others to answer as you usually do and make it sound pretty, ok that’s an opinion that I believe to be true but I will compare licensing any day of the week as others have asked in the past.

Comment: Wow, I was not trying to relight a 3-year-old argument.  Thanks a load there @DavidM.Karr.  I give up, I'm just deleting my answer. **I'm here to help people**. What are you here for?